# TSQL to select a columns distinct value, but show the row with the least amount of NULL values

Tags: t-sql, distinct-values

I have the following columns

```
COL1 COL2   COL3    COL4
1    2      NULL    Value1
1    NULL   NULL    Value1
1    NULL   NULL    Value2
1    3      NULL    Value2

The result set I want is 

COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
1        2      NULL    Value1
1        3      NULL    Value2
```

The logic to this is that if there is a Distinct Value in COL 4 it should be shown, however only ever one row for each distinct value.
The one row to be shown should have the least amount of NULL valued columns of any row with that distinct value

A bit stuck on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will the number of columns being checked for `null` values change?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are applying this to a reasonably static table you can apply a `row_number` grouped by each `Col4` value, ordered by the count of the other columns that aren't `null`:

```
declare @t table(Col1 int,Col2 int,Col3 int,Col4 nvarchar(6));
insert into @t values
 (1,2   ,NULL,'Value1')
,(1,NULL,NULL,'Value1')
,(1,NULL,NULL,'Value2')
,(1,3   ,NULL,'Value2')
;

with d as
(
    select Col1
            ,Col2
            ,Col3
            ,Col4
            ,row_number() over (partition by Col4
                                order by case when Col1 is null then 1 else 0 end
                                        +case when Col2 is null then 1 else 0 end
                                        +case when Col3 is null then 1 else 0 end
                               ) as rn
    from @t
)
select Col1
        ,Col2
        ,Col3
        ,Col4
from d
where rn = 1
;
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |  Col4  |
+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    2 | NULL | Value1 |
|    1 |    3 | NULL | Value2 |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Why would the table need to be "reasonably static"?

Comment: @RichardWatts  I mean with regard to the number of columns.  If there are a lot of columns added or removed that need to be checked in the count of `null` values, you would either need to constantly update this query or make it dynamic.  Being set based, the number of rows changing doesn't really matter.